# Are WINE questions about a specific Mac configuration appropriate?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

If I wanted to ask a question about whether or not WINE, on a specific configuration of MacBook (assuming I provided the appropriate specifications), would work for a given software title, is that appropriate for this StackExchange site?

(I'd say that 90% of the time, this sort of question will be gaming-related, so there is overlap between here and the gaming SE site. However, there are the remaining occasions, where there might be overlap between here and Super User.)

I ask because now that I have WINE installed, I might want to try some (slightly-older) PC games on it. And while I know most games from, say, a decade ago, will work (EG, Fallout and Fallout 2), I don't know about others. Do I ask here, at gaming, or perhaps use Google-fu and experimentation to find out? (It's cool if the questions aren't OK here nor at gaming, I just want to be on the safe side either way!)

Answer (score 3):

I *think* it would be fine, but the worst thing that could happen is it gets closed. I would actually have to see the question to have a better opinion.